# Cocoapods not working with remote Artifactory repo

Tags: ios, cocoapods, artifactory

I have cocoapods v1.10.1 and cocoapods-art v1.0.5 installed.

My pod file looks like this:

```
platform :ios, '12.0'

plugin 'cocoapods-art', :sources => [
    'cocoaPods-remote'
]

target 'MyApp' do
    inhibit_all_warnings!
    use_frameworks!

    pod 'Adjust', '4.28.0'
    pod 'AdobeMobileSDK', '4.20.0'
    pod 'Firebase/Core', '6.34.0'
    pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig', '6.34.0'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '6.34.0'
    pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics', '6.34.0'
    pod 'Firebase/Analytics', '6.34.0'
    pod 'GoogleAppMeasurement', '6.9.0'

end
```

I have only 1 remote repo ("cocoaPods-remote") where all my dependencies should pull from.

```
$ pod repo

0 repos

$ pod repo-art

cocoaPods-remote
- URL: https://artifactory.[redacted]/artifactory/api/pods/cocoaPods-remote
- Path: /Users/[redacted]/.cocoapods/repos-art/cocoaPods-remote/

1 repo
```

The "cocoaPods-remote" repo has been installed locally and when I run the `pod install --repo-update` command I get the following error:

```
$ pod install --repo-update
/Users/[redacted]/.cocoapods/repos-art/cocoaPods-remote/.artpodrc
Analyzing dependencies
/Users/[redacted]/.cocoapods/repos-art/cocoaPods-remote/.artpodrc
[!] Unable to find a specification for `Adjust (= 4.28.0)`

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
```

I've tried multiple different versions of CocoaPods and still same issue.
I've following the documentation in artifacory about setting this up but it hasn't changed anything.
I'm not sure what else to try, any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: This might be unrelated, but in my case I needed to run `pod repo-art update MY-REMOTE-NAME`, and only then `pod install` managed to go through. In fact, it seems that I need to run `pod repo-art update MY-REMOTE-NAME` every time something changes in that repository in Artifactory. I'd expect `pod install --repo-update` to take care of that, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I know this issue is very old but I was facing the same problem as @kd02 and wanted to share what solved this problem on my side.

A remote repository is first of all caching artifacts. In case of cocoapods (and not only) there is an index tarball which is as well cached on the remote.

The first time someone downloads an artifact through the remote repo this index is cached. By default the "Metadata retrieval cache period" is set to 7200 seconds.

Which means, every request within this period will return the cached index.

In case a new version of a cocoapods artifact is published to the upstream repository the index won't be re-downloaded by the client within the 7200 seconds.

To solve this problem the "Metadata retrieval cache period" needs to be set to 0. This will result that all requests for metadata files will be downloaded always from upstream repo.